# Observable channels in RXJS with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

*I already know that in order to enable communication between components (or other parts) - I can create a centralized Injectable service :*

```
@Injectable()
export class PubSubService
{
    private publishSubscribeSubject_: Subject <any> = new Subject();
    emitter_: Observable <any> ;

    constructor()
    {
        this.emitter_ = this.publishSubscribeSubject_.asObservable();
    }

    publish(data:string): void
    {
        this.publishSubscribeSubject_.next(data);
    }
}
```

Now — all injected components can subscribe to the public `emitter_` (without enabled doing `.next(..)`).

*But* then I saw another approach which uses `logic-channels`  - so now the service looks like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class PubSubService {
  private publishSubscribeSubject_:Subject<any> = new Subject();
  emitter_:Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.emitter_ = this.publishSubscribeSubject_.asObservable();
  }

  publish(channel:string, event:any):void {
    this.publishSubscribeSubject_.next({
      channel: channel,
      event: event
    });
  }

  subscribe(channel:string, handler:((value:any) => void)):Subscriber {
    return this.emitter_
      .filter(emission => emission.channel === channel)
      .map(emission => emission.event)
      .subscribe(handler);
  }
}
```

Those channels are merely strings which are bypassed to the elements via  :

```
  <node subscribeChannel="foo"   publishChannel="bar">
  </node>
  <node subscribeChannel="bar"   publishChannel="foo">
  </node>
```

*Notice* how two same-type-nodes subscribe to a *different* channel and publish to *different* channels.

`NodeComponent` is :

```
export class NodeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input() publishChannel:string;
  @Input() subscribeChannel:string;
  count:number = 0;
  private pubSubServiceSubscription_:Subscription;


  constructor(private pubSubService_:PubSubService) {}

  send() {
    this.pubSubService_
      .publish(this.publishChannel, {});
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pubSubService_
      .subscribe(this.subscribeChannel, 
                 event => ++this.count);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pubSubServiceSubscription_.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**Question:**

What (if any) do I gain from this infrastructure  ?

I can think that it allows me to subscribe to a specific `"banana"` channel within a `fruits Subject`  (which can't deal with `"furnitures"`).

But when I think about it all subscribers to fruits will have a reference to that subject .

What is a benefit in that structure , and in what scenarios will it help me ?

*( I would love to see an example where not using it , will do something bad).*

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y1T3ycCByiMqYHOFPTAw?p=preview)

Comment: I use Rxjs to create an Event Emitter system, suppose you don't want using `logic-channels`, each event you wanna publish, you need create one `service` for it. Now with event system or `channels` you could create one, and use in different scenario. This is my Event Emitter https://gist.github.com/tieppt/f218867a4184f2d7b24c0ececad77f61

Comment: something like that.